# Create a file using Runtime.exec using echo in linux?

Tags: java, linux, shell, terminal, echo

I'm having trouble using Runtime.exec in Java, it seems some commands work while others do not. For example if I run

```
echo some data > data.txt
```

In my terminal it works fine, however if I try and use Java to do this it doesn't work.

```
Runtime mRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process mProcess = mRuntime.exec("echo some data > data.txt");
mProcess.waitFor();
```

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Besides the other advice, read and implement **all** the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Answer (score 8):

`echo` is not a real command in the sense that it has a binary that you can run. It is a built-in function of shells.

You could try running a shell like `cmd.exe` in Windows or `sh` in Linux/Mac/Unix, and then passing the command to run as a string.. Like using 'bash', you can do this:

**edit because redirection is a little different using `Runtime`**

To do redirection correctly, you should be using the form of `exec` that takes a `String[]`.

Here's a quick example that does work with redirection.

```
public class RunTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String [] commands = { "bash", "-c", "echo hello > hello.txt" };
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
   }
}
```

But if you just wanted to create a file, you could create the file with Java's own API rather than use `Runtime`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work either. While in the Terminal it works fine, it still fails to do anything when I run it using exec.

Comment: @JohnSmith1995 - updated my answer, you have to invoke the command a little differently via Java.

Comment: Thanks! was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

That is because `echo` is a shell internal command not a program that can be executed!
Try running instead `bash -c "echo some data > data.txt"`