# How to communicate with arduino and java in serial port?

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I was trying to send a message to Arduino (to test if the Arduino received any message the motor will turn on), the following code works if I run on Terminal

```
echo 1 > /dev/ttyACM0
```

But I tried this in Java

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo 1 > /dev/ttyACM0");
```

Anyone knows how to execute in Arduino Serial port?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a file using Runtime.exec?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914045/create-a-file-using-runtime-exec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the RXTX lib for Java serial connections.

Very similar code to what worked for me is shown here:

https://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2008/08/08/how-to-open-serial-port-using-rxtx/

Answer (score 0):

Try [RXTX](https://github.com/rxtx/rxtx) library, this is Java wrapper for the serial port. [Project website.](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)
Example: [source](https://github.com/rtatol/serial-event-listener-arduino)

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't provide support for serial communications out of the box. You need to use a 3rd party library or extension.
Oracle do provide one - Java Communications API

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html

I have used this in the past with AVR Micro-controllers. There are several tutorials on the net to get it up and running.