# Linux Command not working using java if it contains special symbol

Tags: java, linux, bash, process, execution

I am trying to run the below code but it is not working, can someone help me understand why it is behaving like this or am i missing something?

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class SimpleClass {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash mkdir demoDir");
            // Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo sometext >> someFile.txt");
            }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If i execute the first process it is working fine but if i execute process2 it is not working.  someFile.txt is present and the present working directory, apart from this command if i try to make directory like `mkdir /home/dummy/demoDir` then also it is not working but my program gets executed successfully.

Comment: What effect do you think the `bash` has in the first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914045/create-a-file-using-runtime-exec). Use

```
String[] cmd = {"bash", "-c", "echo sometext >> someFile.txt" };
Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

instead. Works for me.

Comment: Thanx Brosch, it worked :) and the link was also useful, i searched it earlier but neither google nor stackoverflow has shown me that answer :(

Answer (score 1):

`>>` is interpreted and processed by your shell (e.g., bash, zsh, etc).  However, you're not running a shell in this command. `Runtime.exec()` basically executes the command `/bin/echo` and passes it the arguments `someText`, `>>`, `someFile.txt`.

I don't know why you want to do what you're doing but try this:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash -c \"echo sometext >> someFile.txt\"");`

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanx for the answer but i tried it before and it was not working and i tried your answer again but still it didn't worked

Answer (score -1):

You cannot execute echo command without shell -> add bash to begin of th